# beamer- change author/speaker in middle of presentation?

Tags: beamer

I will be making a presentation with another speaker (obviously, a co-author on the project).   We each have our slides set up with the same template and are ready to merge our halves of the talk together.   What I would like to have happen is that the (short) author and institution that appears in the footer of the slides to change away from me and into my coauthor's data when he speaks.  Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?  Nothing in the user guide is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely, since the paper is co-authored you should have *both* your names on all the slides.  The slides reflect the content of the paper (and its authors) not who's speaking at the time.

However, if you really want to do this, you can simply issue a new `\author` command before the first frame of your co-author.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{EastLansing}

\begin{document}
\author[Author1]{Author 1 and Author 2}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Frame title}
\end{frame}
\author[Author2]{Author 1 and Author 2}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Fair point.  However, this project has four coauthors, and I didn't want to overcrowd the footer with too much text.  Thanks for your help.